GITLAB Semgrep SAST on multi module java maven project
I have included the SAST template in my gitlab yml file. Its a java maven multi module project and SEMGREP is just scanning the root folder but not the sub folder. Dont see any such information in the log file.
Does it support scanning the multi modules of a project. If  yes, then what is the setting?
Any help would be appreciated.
Not sure where can I specify the paths or there is something that its is expecting from the previous build job [mvn clean install]
